# stlport compilation with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (msvc9) on Windows 7 x64 doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, stlport

I downloaded stlport from https://stlport.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/stlport/trunk/STLport and tried to compile it with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on Windows 7 x64.
The readme says to use: configure -c msvc9 but -c is an unknown compiler option so I used: configure msvc9
This seems to work according to the output, but it doesn't. The build/lib dir stays empty.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using STLPort?  The Microsoft STL implementation as of VS2005 is very good.

Comment: @Steve: Agreed, I have no quibbles with the MSVC9 STL implementation.

Comment: I use stlport to compile DC++, I don't think this is possible without the stlport

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122057/has-anyone-already-done-the-work-to-make-stlport-build-with-vs2008-and-or-an-x64  perhaps

Comment: This is not a dup because with the current svn version I still get errors! When I use the makefiles from http://strongdc.sourceforge.net/download/STLPort.7z and I copy all the svn files over the files in this 7z I still get: http://pastebin.com/u5qHd36n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I use "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt" (for the vars and paths) with the configure script from http://strongdc.sourceforge.net/download/STLPort.7z and I copy all the svn files over the files in this 7z
Then I replace every "_*value" with "*_stlvalue" in stlport\stlport\type_traits.
In the folder "stlport\build\lib>" I execute "configure -c msvc9" and after that "nmake /f msvc.mak clean install".

The configure script that I downloaded from the svn still says:
"
c:\stlport>configure -c msvc9
STLport Configuration Tool for Windows

Unknown compiler: -c

Unknown option: msvc9

Setting platform: Windows XP

Done configuring STLport.
"

(I use the script from the 7z that I downloaded)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the configure script just create the configuration like it does for most Unix-type software? Admittedly it's been a while since I used STLport but I think that you might have to run configure first and the probably a second build step involving nmake/make to kick off the actual build.

Comment: yes I know, but the configure doesn't configure anything. The next step is to go into build/lib and use nmake, but the makefile isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

For DC++ the compilation instructions [here](http://dcplusplus.sourceforge.net/webhelp/compile.html) suggest that for MSVC9 (SP1) you don't need STLPort since tr1 containers are already in SP1.  Have you tried running through this?

> Compiler
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 (2008) with
>   at least Service Pack 1:
>
> Get
>   https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=17034&wa=wsignin1.0,
>   a hotfixed-hotfix which fixes SP1.
>   Download OpenSSL from www.openssl.org
>   and compile it. You should get
>   libraries called libeay32.lib and
>   ssleay32.lib; copy them in
>   openssl/lib. To compile DC++ in debug
>   mode, OpenSSL libraries have to be
>   compiled in debug mode too (read their
>   instructions file; it's a matter of
>   adding "debug" in the do_* file you
>   use). Rename debug libraries to
>   libeay32d.lib and ssleay32d.lib; put
>   them in openssl/lib.

STLPort is not in the dependency list, unless you use "Other" compilers without TR1 containers.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that. I can now compile with or without stlport, thanks.